Magento 2.4.3. to 2.4.6 upgrade error
When i try and upgrade my Magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6 i get this error now.
    [ab140e0b@cloudhost-82289 html]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laminas/laminas-dom ^3.7, found laminas/laminas-dom[2.0.0, ..., 2.15.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - amasty/module-hide-price-subscription-pack 1.7.1 requires amasty/module-hide-price >=1.7.1 -> satisfiable by amasty/module-hide-price[1.7.1].
    - amasty/module-hide-price-subscription-pack 1.7.0 requires amasty/module-hide-price >=1.7.0 -> satisfiable by amasty/module-hide-price[1.7.0, 1.7.1].
    - amasty/module-hide-price[1.7.0, ..., 1.7.1] require laminas/laminas-dom * -> found laminas/laminas-dom[2.0.0, ..., 2.14.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.7).
    - Root composer.json requires amasty/module-hide-price-subscription-pack ^1.7 -> satisfiable by amasty/module-hide-price-subscription-pack[1.7.0, 1.7.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Anyone know how to solve this?
Edited Question
Problem 1
    - zendframework/zend-uri 2.5.2 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-uri 2.5.2 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - zendframework/zend-soap[2.5.2, ..., 2.6.0] require php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0, ..., 2.8.0] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires bambora/module-payment-magento2 ^2.3 -> satisfiable by bambora/module-payment-magento2[2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.4, 2.3.5].
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] require laminas/laminas-validator ^2.39 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-validator[2.39.0, ..., 2.64.1].
    - laminas/laminas-validator[2.39.0, ..., 2.62.0] require laminas/laminas-servicemanager ^3.21.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-servicemanager[3.21.0, 3.22.0, 3.22.1].
    - laminas/laminas-servicemanager 3.21.0 requires laminas/laminas-stdlib ^3.17 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.17.0, 3.18.0, 3.19.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.17.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-servicemanager 3.22.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - laminas/laminas-validator[2.63.0, ..., 2.64.1] require laminas/laminas-stdlib ^3.19 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.19.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.19.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6].
    - bambora/module-payment-magento2[2.3.1, ..., 2.3.5] require zendframework/zend-soap ^2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.4.6, ..., 2.8.0].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.13 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.13 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.13].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.12 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.12 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.12].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.11 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.11 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.11].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.10 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.10 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.10].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.9 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.9 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.9].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.8 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.8 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.8].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.7 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.7].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.4.6 requires zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-uri[2.4.6].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.5.0 requires zendframework/zend-uri ~2.5.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-uri[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2], zendframework/zend-uri[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2].
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.5.1.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.5.0.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.13.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.12.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.11.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.10.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.9.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.8.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.7.
    - laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] conflict with zendframework/zend-uri 2.4.6.
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: laminas/laminas-uri[2.5.0, ..., 2.12.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 requires laminas/laminas-uri ^2.9 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-uri[2.9.0, ..., 2.12.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laminas/laminas-uri 2.10.0 (conflict analysis result)


please delete composer.lock file from magento root and then run composer install command.
composer.lock will be recreate based on your magento composer.json dependency and packages.
I hope you already executed composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update 

Did not help, I got this new error code when I tried the composer install command. I have updated the question with the new error code.


setup blank 2.4.6 project
copy composer.lock from this blank project to the project you want to update
update magento/product-community-edition version to 2.4.6 in composer.json
run composer update of all your custom modules from composer.json, update them if possible/necessary to the highest version


1.Revert any changes you made to the composer.json file to ensure it reflects the correct dependencies.
2.Check your auth.json file to verify that your public and private keys are correct and valid.
3.Once everything is in order, run the following commands:
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush

